# Converting a Direction Vector rotation to Euller Angle rotation

Tags: trigonometry

I was looking for this answer in many related topics but couldn't find exactly what I need.

My problem is: I have a body flat to a world coordinate system, which the direction vector for it is [0 0 -1]. This body is rotated getting to the following new direction [x1 y1 z1]. What I need is, knowing x1, y1 and z1 to calculate the rotation angles Rx, Ry and Rz to move the body from first position to the new one.

The assumptions for this problem are:

- Rotations are done in fixed world frame (extrinsic rotation);
- Sequence of rotation is Rx, Ry and Rz (Tait-Bryan Angles);
- Assume right-hand rule for signs of rotation.

The closest solution for me was working with the following rotation matrix. This rotation matrix is used for fixed world frame in xyz sequence and for column vectors (pre-multiplication). 1 2 3 are references to Rx, Ry and Rz angles. C and S are references to sin ans cos function.

[Rotation Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCTYb.jpg)

So basically what I've done was to multiply this rotation matrix to [0 0 -1] (in column vector) = [x1 y1 z1] (in column vector). This leads me to an equation system like this:

-c1*c3*s2 - s1*s3 = x1

-c1*s2*s3 + c3*s1 = y1

-c1*c2            = z1

I tested a few values in this system and it works well. Althought I can't find a solution for the system.

Can anyone find a solution for the system or any other workaround for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Formatting tips here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264 to make your question easier to follow.

Comment: To get a full solution to the problem you need to specify the images of at least two vectors (ideally two orthogonal vectors). Specifying the image of only (0,0,-1) is insufficient, because it leaves open what happens to the (angles) of points in a plane orthogonal to (0,0,-1).